# How to get metadata from SSAS and SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ssas-2008

How can I get the generated metadata in data Cube designed and deployed SQL Server Analysis Services(SSAS) 2008 R 2?

Comment: Please ask one question in each question. You should create a second question for the "second part" of your question.

Comment: You should also be more specific about what "metadata" you are referring to.

Comment: One question per question please, please include more details. I removed the second question.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to extract it from the XML files deployed with the Analysis Services database -